# Genymotion Device does not boot up

Tags: boot, virtualbox, kubuntu, genymotion

[image: Stuck at "Starting Virtual Device"]
[image: But running in Virtual box]

I'm on Kubuntu 16.10 and my problem is that all the virtual devices I create get stuck there forever. It works fine on Windows 10 so I don't know what's going on.

I've already tried opening it 100 times and reinstalling genymotion and the virtual device
Also similar problem [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632576/ubuntu-16-04-unrecognized-opengl-version/42690358#42690358)

Log file:[Genymotion Device.log](http://pastebin.com/ME2Zfsgi)

Comment: You could use pastebin.org to paste your log files, then paste the link here for us to look at. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include  whether you are experiencing this issue with one or both of your virtual devices (as well as adding the requested link to a [pastebin log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: In the end of the log file, it shows an error "unrecognized opengl version"

Comment: Maybe thats the problem, but i don't understand what that means

Comment: Linked with http://stackoverflow.com/q/42632576/4244605

Answer (score 3):

That can happen if your system has an ATI card.
Removing the libdrm.so.2 file from Genymotion directory or just rename like 
 [image: Rename file]
 then just hit genymotion to run and it should be fixed.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690358/4244605)

Comment: genius!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: what should be the location of this file?